# Reuse results from Observables in other step of the RX flow

Tags: android, rx-java, facebook-sdk-4.0

I made a wrapper for `Facebook api` to login and get the logged user.
In my api I need to

1. login with facebook,
2. login with my api
3. update user with her `facebook id`.

All of CustomerRepository and FacebookRepository methods returns Observables.

So first I do `mFacebookRepository.startLoginFlow()` to login the user with fb.

The result from this is the Facebook user that is will be used by `mCustomerRepository.loginWithFacebook` and `mCustomerRepository.updateFacebookId` but this one should be called only if `loginWithFacebook` worked.

I tried using an external final array but looks really bad to me.

`final String[] facebookUserId = new String[1];
Subscription subscription = mFacebookRepository.startLoginFlow()
    .compose(applyIoSchedulers())
    .switchMap(user -> { 
          facebookUserId[0] = user.getId(); // Save it for reuse later :(
          mCustomerRepository.loginWithFacebook(user);
     })
    .switchMap(session -> mCustomerRepository.getCurrent())
    .switchMap(customer -> mCustomerRepository.updateFacebookId(customer, facebookUserId[0]) // Reused here)
    .subscribe(user -> {
      mView.dismissProgress();
      mView.startLoggedView();
      mView.close();
    }, error -> {
      mView.dismissProgress();
      manageErrorFlow(error);
    });`

how can I share the facebook user id with more than one subscriber?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I haven't worked with facebook SDK + Rx, but I created some fake objects and functions which reproduce behaviour of your code.

Please, take a look and let me know if you need any help:

```
public static class FacebookCredential{
    public FacebookCredential(User u, Device device){};
}
public static class Device{
}
public static class Session{
}
public static class Customer{
}

public Device loadDeviceToken(){
    return null;
}

public Session loginWithFacebook(){
    return null;
}

public Customer getCurrent(){
    return null;
}

public User updateFacebookId(Customer c, String userId){
    return null;
}

private void test(){
    Observable.just(new User())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<User>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<User> call(final User user) {
                    return Observable.just(loadDeviceToken())
                            .map(new Func1<Device, FacebookCredential>() {
                                @Override
                                public FacebookCredential call(Device device) {
                                    return new FacebookCredential(user, device);
                                }
                            })
                            .map(new Func1<FacebookCredential, Session>() {
                                @Override
                                public Session call(FacebookCredential facebookCredential) {
                                    return loginWithFacebook();
                                }
                            })
                            .map(new Func1<Session, Customer>() {
                                @Override
                                public Customer call(Session session) {
                                    return getCurrent();
                                }
                            })
                            .map(new Func1<Customer, User>() {
                                @Override
                                public User call(Customer customer) {
                                    return updateFacebookId(customer, user.getId());
                                }
                            });

                }
            }).subscribe(/*...*/);
}
```

Or using lambdas:

```
public static class FacebookCredential{
    public FacebookCredential(User u, Device device){};
}
public static class Device{
}
public static class Session{
}
public static class Customer{
}

public Device loadDeviceToken(){
    return null;
}

public Session loginWithFacebook(){
    return null;
}

public Customer getCurrent(){
    return null;
}

public User updateFacebookId(Customer c, String userId){
    return null;
}

private void test(){
    Observable.just(new User())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(user -> Observable.just(loadDeviceToken())
                    .map(device -> new FacebookCredential(user, device))
                    .map(facebookCredential -> loginWithFacebook())
                    .map(session -> getCurrent())
                    .map(customer -> updateFacebookId(customer, user.getId()))).subscribe(/*...*/);
}
```

Comment: but theres a confusion, User is not the same as Customer, facebook give me a user, then I use that user to do multiple things, but how to use it in different steps of the chain?

Comment: @danielgomezrico, as you can see, in my code, user isn't same to customer.
I just haven't included `user` object into code.
Actually, I don't understand what do you mean, in code above, you can use `User` object in different steps of chain, isn't it?
in `.map(device -> new FacebookCredential(user, device))` and `.map(customer -> updateFacebookId(customer, user.getId()))`
And this code should work for you.

Comment: @danielgomezrico just replace my fake functions and objects to certain from facebook, and it should work

Comment: but if I use user in other lambdas its out of scope

Comment: @danielgomezrico could you please post your code?
For code, which you have posted in the question, this solution should work

Comment: question updated, all the functions from the repositories returns Observables.